# Angular project options into child component

Tags: angular

I'd like to project select options into a child component with ng-content like this:

```
<custom-select>
  <option *ngFor="let name of names" [ngValue]="name">{{ name.name }}</option>
</custom-select>
```

In the child component, I use a compare function, called by [compareWith] and ng-content.

```
<select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [compareWith]="compareB">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</select>
```

If I inject the options with ng-content from the parent component, the compareWith function is not triggered. If I do the same with options inside the child component, it works.

I have a Stackblitz example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymoj4d?file=src/app/app.component.html

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

In your **custom-select.component.ts** add select attribute to ng-content

```
<select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [compareWith]="compareB">
  <ng-content select="[options]"></ng-content>
</select>
{{ selectedValue.name }}
```

and then in your **app.component.ts** add defined selector of content projection to option:

```
<custom-select>
  <option options *ngFor="let name of names" [ngValue]="name">{{ name.name }}</option>
</custom-select>
```

Comment: That seems not to work... compareB ist still not called. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I think that there is some issue with content projection and compareWith function. Looks like the event which should call out compareWith has not been catched or do not emit at all..